# In LyX, is it possible to customize the special characters (specifically symbols)?

Tags: symbols, xetex, lyx

This could be a problem to many newcomers to LyX (and LaTeX in general), who are migrating from word processors; the story is that first I try to insert a special character, an **arrow** for example, so I choose `Insert -> Special Character -> Symbols...` from the menu, and choose the `Arrows` category. That works fine for some fonts such as the **Latin Modern Roman** but not for others such as **Palatino**.

The next thing I would try is to use symbols from the **Dingbats** category. And again, it doesn't always work with errors such as `l.31 \textrightarrow{}\FiveStarConvex
                                     {}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.`

The third thing I would do is to change the encoding to unicode by putting `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble (can also be done through the `Document -> Settings` dialog). This has the effect of adding many other dingbats to the **dingbats** symbol category. But again, this seems to be useless (at least from a beginner's point of view).

My problem in summary is that I'm not able to insert special symbols from the `Insert -> Special Character -> Symbols...` dialog the way I can in *Open Office Writer* for example. Is it possible to make symbol insertion more usable, probably through some configuration?

Or may be using **XeTeX** helps in this situation? I tried **XeTeX** actually but it ignored the symbols I inserted, obviously because they are not supported in the font I was using.

So any clue, or tutorial on this?

I found that some fonts include representation for Dingbats, such as **FreeSerif**. Other fonts such as Times New Roman don't. I also found that the **Character Map tool** of Gnome doesn't show that some characters are not provided by some fonts. So may be I just need to use **XeTeX**, and find an alternative to the Gnome Character Map tool to know which fonts provide which symbols.

Comment: I installed the fontmatrix program and strangely enough, I found that FreeSerif doesn't have glyphs for Dingbats, though I could include Dingbats in a sample XeTeX document using FreeSerif!

Comment: This is essentially a feature request for Lyx, and therefore not actually a question we can answer.